# Android Translate One Language to Another and Text to Speech

Tags: android, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

I am trying to make an application in which user can translate text one language to another and will be able to hear the translated text.

I Somehow Done Translating One Language to another using Microsoft Translate API.

But I am still unable to to speak out that translated text.

Please Guide me, How to achieve this functionality.

You can suggest me totally different API with translation and speech, I can convert my project to that.

Please Please any help.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can you Google's text to speech. See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html).

Comment: they provide some limited languages, I want some more languages for speech.
How can I implement that language e.g. Urdu, Arabic Norwegian, Danish, Dutch etc.